# How many hours is needed for training the acoustic model

Tags: cmusphinx

I want to build a English acoustic model for children under 14 in China, with about 800 words in vocabulary, using cmusphinx.

I did some research that some commercial voice engine take thousands of hours of voice record to train their acoustic model: (nuance and google spent 2000+ and 1000+ hours).

For I need to achieve about 95% a accurate rate, How many hours  do I need  for the voice corpus ?

Is it the longer the voice corpus is, the better accurate rate it will achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

300-400 hours is a good amount of data. Less than 100 will not work.

With the increase of the data size you will not necessary get an increase in accuracy if the training data itself has systematic issues, however, if you properly analyze issues in a training data, the result could potentially improve.

If you study machine learning in general, the course would cover data preparation issues.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply .for more:how many people do I need for the acoutic model ? Is there a formula of computer the hours we need for training data according to vocabulary ?  I ref some number from here [link](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam) [link](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinxman/FAQ.html)

Comment: No, there is no formula.